# How to get HttpSession in a JAX-RS service method?

Tags: jax-rs, httpsession

I am trying to get the HTTP session in my JAX-RS service. Usually I use in a JSF managed bean:

```
HttpSession session = (HttpSession) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSession(false);
```

But this time I need it in a JAX-RS service method. So the current instance of `FacesContext` is null. Is there another way to get it? I tried with contextual injection of `HttpServletRequest`, but I couldn't make it work.

Comment: If its a REST application why a session state being attached to the application?Is this a true REST application?

Comment: Actually it's a JEE application with primefaces. I use Resteay in this specific case ^^

Comment: I know that you can get the session this way btw:
`@Context
HttpServletRequest req;
...
req.getSession()`

The problem is that my "jax-rs method" calls like 5 or 6 other methods before I need access to the request and I can't add the HttpServletRequest as a parameter to all those methods :s